# How to avoid ListView put rows with TextView transparent

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm developing a Chat App, so I create  a list of friends.

Take a look at my ListView declaration at layout.xml

```
<ListView
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/usersList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerPadding="2dp"
        android:overScrollFooter="@null"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:transcriptMode="normal"
        />
```

And the behavior of this ListView is annoying.

When I run my app in a phone with Android 2.3 the TextView itens of my ListView becomes transparent just like the image below:

[image]

Sometimes when a press the itens the color of TextView back to normality.

When I run my app in a phone with Android 4.1 this problem not happens.

[image]

My user item xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/quick_blox_user" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:id="@+id/text_view_user"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="asdasdad"
                android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

                <TextView 
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:id="@+id/text_view_user_last_activity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="asdasdad"
                android:textColor="@color/text_gray_light"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_pending_messages"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_message_pending_number"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/color_new_message_title"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:text="12"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_user_last_activity"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:text="@string/pending_messages"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_new_message"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Adapter:

```
public class UserAdapter extends BaseCustomAdapter<UserItem> {

    public UserAdapter(Activity a, List<UserItem> d) {
        super(a, d); 
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate( R.layout.user_quickblox_item, null);  
        }

        UserItem user  = data.get(position); 

        String userLogin = user.getUser().getLogin();
        int index = userLogin.indexOf("@");
        if(index != -1) {
            userLogin = userLogin.substring(0, index);
        }
        int count = ChatMessageDAO.getInstance(activity).countMessagePendentBySenderId(user.getUser().getId());

        View viewPendingMessages = view.findViewById(R.id.layout_pending_messages);
        if(count == 0) {
            viewPendingMessages.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            viewPendingMessages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Button buttonMessageNumberIndicator = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button_message_pending_number);
            buttonMessageNumberIndicator.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        }

        TextView textViewUser = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_user);
        textViewUser.setText(userLogin);

        TextView textViewUserLastActivity = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_user_last_activity);


        long diff = new Date().getTime() - user.getUser().getLastRequestAt().getTime();  
        long diffInDays =  TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        if(diffInDays == 0) {
            long diffInHours =  TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            if(diffInHours == 0) {
                long diffInMinutes =  TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                if(diffInMinutes < 0) {
                    textViewUserLastActivity.setText("Esta online agora");  
                }  else {
                    textViewUserLastActivity.setText("Entrou hoje " + diffInMinutes+ " minuto(s) atrás");   
                }
            } else {
                textViewUserLastActivity.setText("Entrou hoje " + diffInHours+ " horas atrás");
            }

        } else if(diffInDays == 1) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(user.getUser().getLastRequestAt());
            int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); 
            textViewUserLastActivity.setText("Entrou ontem as " + hour + " horas");  
        } else {
            textViewUserLastActivity.setText("Entrou " + diffInDays  + " dia(s) atras");    
        }

        return view;
    } 

}
```

How to avoid this problem?

Comment: The code you posted is not the place to set the list items text colour. add your xml layout for the list item. the one that is inflating in get view method

Comment: Ok. I update my Issue with these information. But I don't change the TextView Color anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved my problem was **android:background**:

```
<LinearLayout
```

> **android:background="@android:color/white**

```
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:id="@+id/text_view_user"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="asdasdad"
                android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

                <TextView 
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:id="@+id/text_view_user_last_activity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="asdasdad"
                android:textColor="@color/text_gray_light"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
```

At my LinearLayout which has the TextViews at my user_item.xml(The layout of itens of the List). I put background color as White. Its strange because the main ViewGroup of this layout is already set with background color White. Now My itens appears normally.

An Annoying solution for an Annoying problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that the TextViews are not showing at all. not the colour is changing. you can check that by setting a background for the textviews.

A few mistakes in the item xml I would like to point out:

1. You have two items in the horizontal layout. the linear layout that contains the image and the linear layout that contains textview. In this case you can't have them both match_parent. the total size would be screen size * 2.
2. when setting weight for a linear layout in a horizontal container you set the width to 0dp.
3. your weight sum is 1 + 0.5 = 1.5. means that the image will reserve 2/3 of screen size and textview 1/3. looks un-logical.

These un logical values could cause different layout display for different os version.

Solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            **android:layout_width="0dp"**
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            **android:layout_weight="1"**
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/quick_blox_user" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            **android:layout_width="0dp"**
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            **android:layout_weight="2"**
            android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:id="@+id/text_view_user"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="asdasdad"
                android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

                <TextView 
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:id="@+id/text_view_user_last_activity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="asdasdad"
                android:textColor="@color/text_gray_light"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_pending_messages"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_message_pending_number"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/color_new_message_title"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:text="12"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_user_last_activity"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:text="@string/pending_messages"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_new_message"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Also, you have a lot of unneeded layouts.

Comment: Everything you say makes sense for me, I followed all your tips. Unfortunately its not solved the problem. I believe it is a attribute of ListView, because sometimes when I scroll my List the TextViews appear normally. It's a very strange behavior and it's not happen in all devices happens mainly at these devices with Android 2.3.